# How to use fonts-awesome loading image

Tags: css, fonts

I made a simple page to test the problem. I want to use a subset of `font-awesome` icons to I used `IcoMoon` to generate it. Then I made the following `.css` file:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'fontawesome-webfont';
src: url('file:///C:/Users/i/Desktop/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('file:///C:/Users/i/Desktop/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix'), 
     url('file:///C:/Users/i/Desktop/fontawesome-webfont.woff'), 
     url('file:///C:/Users/i/Desktop/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'), 
     url('file:///C:/Users/i/Desktop/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And in my `.html` file I have the relevant `css` :

```
<style>
.icon:after {
    content : '\f110';
    font-family: 'fontawesome-webfont';
}
</style>
```

and html:

```
<span class="icon"></span>
<br />
```

This way I see the image but it's static. From the official page of `fonts-awesome` i read this:

> Use the icon-spin class to get any icon to rotate. Works well with
>   icon-spinner and icon-refresh.

And the following example:

```
<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large"></i> Spinner icon when loading content...
```

the above is not doing anything for me. So I copy-pasted the styles for `.icon-spin` which seems to be:

```
-moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: initial;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: initial;
animation-fill-mode: initial;
animation-play-state: initial;
```

to my `.icon` class but still the image is not rotating. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, so how can I make the image to rotate in this simple example. The only requirement is to use `content : '\f110';` style, because I saw several ways of including fonts and this is the one that I'm sticking to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use complete css of `font-awesome` look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jacerhea/ud8uepo7/5/)

Comment: I can't see the CSS, it seems to appear blank. Can you help me with this, or just copy-paste it in your answer?

Comment: You have to use complete css file of Font-Awesome

Comment: You can download it from his site, here the Link: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: If you use smaller bits of font-awesome it doesn't load the webfonts file.